# Nested JSON Objects with Dimple.js

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, dimple.js

I'm attempting to create a stacked bar chart with Dimple.JS and D3. However, the JSON file I wish to use with this particular visualization involves nested JSON objects (below). The stacked bar chart I wish to create has the channel category as its x-axis, with the y axis to be the aggregate count of the different locations (with each location as a 'stack'). Here is the original data:

```
[{
    "channel": "politics",
    "locations": 
    [{
        "name":"usa", 
        "count" : 1454
        },
    {
        "name":"mexico",
        "count":3543
        },
    {
        "name":"antarctica",
        "count":4352
    }]
},
{
    "channel": "economics",
    "locations": 
    [{
        "name":"usa", 
        "count" : 12431
        },
    {
        "name":"mexico",
        "count":314
        },
    {
        "name":"china",
        "count":2321
        }]
}]
```

I've flattened the above into the JSON below, but I am having trouble using Dimple's .addSeries() method to create the stack.

```
[
{
    "channel": "politics",
    "locations[0].name": "usa",
    "locations[0].count": 1454,
    "locations[1].name": "mexico",
    "locations[1].count": 3543,
    "locations[2].name": "antarctica",
    "locations[2].count": 4352
},
{
    "channel": "economics",
    "locations[0].name": "usa",
    "locations[0].count": 12431,
    "locations[1].name": "mexico",
    "locations[1].count": 314,
    "locations[2].name": "china",
    "locations[2].count": 2321
}
]
```

**My question is this: how can Dimple support either this data encoded in this particular JSON file? Most samples use CSV and TSV files, but I unfortunately have the limit of using only JSON files.**

Answer (score 0):

Dimple can't use nested data. You'll have to flatten it on the client side so there's a single JSON object for *each* intersection of channel/location. Here's an example of how to do that with Underscore.js :

```
var chartData = _.chain(data)
.map(function(row, index){
  // for each original row, return a new row for each location
  return _.map(row.locations, function(location){
    return {
      'channel' : row.channel,
      'name' : location.name,
      'count' : location.count
    };
  });
})
.flatten()
.value();
```

(For every row in the original data set, it will return three rows, one for each location. This will return an array of nested arrays, so it calls `flatten` to make the whole array 1 level deep.)

Here's a jsBin showing that in action : http://jsbin.com/nuvihu/edit?html,js,output

(output):
[image]

If this helps, here is what the data ended up looking like :

```
[{"channel":"politics","name":"usa","count":1454},{"channel":"politics","name":"mexico","count":3543},{"channel":"politics","name":"antarctica","count":4352},{"channel":"economics","name":"usa","count":12431},{"channel":"economics","name":"mexico","count":314},{"channel":"economics","name":"china","count":2321}]
```